# jpa criteriabuilder for @ElementCollection

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

What's the equivalent CriteriaBuilder for this simple jpl?

```
TypedQuery<Sample> query = em.createQuery("from Sample s, In(s.friends) f where f = :friend", Sample.class).setParameter("friend", friend);
// query yields: select sample0_.id as id39_ from Sample sample0_ inner join Sample_friends friends1_ on sample0_.id=friends1_.Sample_id where friends1_.friends=?
return query.getResultList();
```

I've tried dozens of formulations using `.in() .join()` and `.member()` to no avail. `.in` only works as a where clause not as part of the from. `.join` seems to require a dereference to an attribute when using in the where. and `.member` only works on non-elemental types (full entities as the contained reference). [I can post my vain attempts. I've used the `join()` mechanism for other collections where the joined object is an entity, but I can't figure out how to use for an element.]